# Query not returning result (but result exists and query works in different project)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have this little problem with a query I have to return a list of items.  Here is the query:

```
 geographic = _iRepository.Geographics.Where(p => p.GeographID == ID)
                             .SingleOrDefault()
                             .Children
                             .SingleOrDefault()
                             .Children
                             .OrderBy(p => p.DisplayOrder).ThenBy(p => p.Name)
                             .ToList();
```

ID (as well as GeographID) are both guids. The problem is that my query gets stuck at the == part, meaning, it never finds a match.  If I set a breakpoint at this part of the code, after it exits, it gives me the following error:

```
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection
```

which is weird since I had the exact same piece of code somewhere else and it worked perfectly!  I should add I am using MVC 4 with Entity Framework and this is a Web Api controller (or is derived from Web Api).  I have researched and heard that I could do `Lazy Loading` but I'm not sure how that works.

I appreciate any and all help!

Comment: Oh sorry! put all `.Include()`s before the `.Where()`

Comment: I also see this error when trying to debug EF code. It usually means there is an error in the query, but this error gets thrown instead. In order to get to the actual issue, I split up the query, doing each step stage by stage, and converting `ToList()` everytime. Eventually you will find the problem in the code, and when you put the code back together again the error you see above will disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the above query didn't work and everything else I tried worked the same way (object getting disposed).  So I decided to use the query appended.  It is not a "solution" but it does get the job done.  Thanks for all the help:

```
geographic = (from g1 in _iEMARepository.Geographics
                             join g2 in _iEMARepository.Geographics
                                on g1.GeographID equals g2.ParentId
                            join g3 in _iEMARepository.Geographics
                                on g2.GeographID equals g3.ParentId
                             where g1.GeographID == ID
                              select g3).OrderBy(p => p.DisplayOrder).ThenBy(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says that you have disposed the DbContext object. inspect your controller code.

Maybe it's cause of creating the controller using scaffolding. If so, inspect the controller code to find somthing like the following:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

Either remove it(not recommended) or put call your DbContext object before it.

Or maybe you dispose your object manually, or declaring your object by a `using()` clause, etc. Anyway, this error occurs because you call the object after disposing it. Inspect your code...

**Update:**

Another guess: It seems that you are using navigation properties in the query. If so, in this case, you should include any NavPr you need. Try something like this:

```
geographic = _iRepository.Geographics.Include("NavPr1")
    .Include("NavPr2").Include("NavPr2.NavPr21")
    .Where(p => p.GeographID == ID)
    .SingleOrDefault()        
     // and the rest of query...
```

Comment: I can post the full action inside of my controller here, and there is truly nothing that "disposes" of the object.  Reason for me to say that is that I have an almost exact duplicate of that query (instead of using the GeographID I use the Name property) and doesn't face this problem. Does it have something to do with Web Api?

Comment: Sorry if I am a bit ignorant as to what you mean by NavPr but could you explain what it is. Thank you

Comment: just Navigation Property... my made abbreviations...!

Comment: That must be the reason of the problem. Try to find what NavPr causing this error and include that. Look at the other query which works and see what NavPr you aren't using there...

Comment: I tried this, but it seems no matter what I do I keep getting the error.  The only way I noticed it doesn't crash is if I bring back a Geographics object, something like this
'Geograph geograph = _iRepository.Geographics.Where(p => p.GeographID == ID).SingleOrDefault();'

Comment: I don't know any more... You said something about `Lazy Loading` at the bottom of your answer. Simply, Lazy loading means that if you get an object from DbContext, its NavPrs are null! So, if you need them, you should include them...

Comment: @Jose Oh sorry! put all `.Include()`s before the `.Where()`

Comment: That still doesn't work. I truly have no idea what it is I'm doing wrong :(